# iOS TableView Cell cutting off top when setting height using systemLayoutSizeFittingSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying calculate the height of each cell in my table.  Currently, I use this.

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width, UILayoutFittingCompressedSize.height);
CGFloat height = [offscreenCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:maximumSize].height;

return height;
```

The problem is that the cell has many labels with a date string label at the top of it and then multiple labels added below that listing the items for that date. This date label is being cut off for some reason in some of the cells. I think it might have to do with the label's string wrapping to a second line and the height not being calculated correctly.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a cell, set it's properties(date label, etc.) call layoutIfNeeded and then calculate this height:

```
MyCustomCell* cell = [myTableView dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId"];

for( NSString* text in arrayOfTexts )
{
    [cell setDateLabelText:text];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width, UILayoutFittingCompressedSize.height);
    CGFloat height = [offscreenCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:maximumSize].height;//now store this height and use it in height for row at index path
}
```